# I want to call a python function from a nodes lambda function in AWS

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda

I have used the spawn module to call a script1.py function from my nodejs export handler but it does not work.
The index.js file is as follows-:

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
  process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']
  //this was added as mentioned in the aws documentation
  let dataToSend
const python = spawn('python', ['script1.py']);
  python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
     dataToSend = data.toString();
    });
  console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)+ dataToSend)
  return dataToSend
}
```

and the python script1.py is as follows-:

```
print('hello from python')
```

I tested it using postman and it gave an internal server error.
I want to run a spacy module hence I need to integrate my python code with my nodejs code.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, because there is no Python installed in the NodeJS runtime.

As far as I can tell, you have three options:

1. [Build a Docker image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) containing NodeJS and Python and use it with AWS Lambda.
2. Port the code from the Python Lambda *into* your NodeJS Lambda.
3. Create two Lambdas. One Python, one NodeJS and invoke one from the other (thanks [manpreet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4556029/manpreet) from the comments)

Comment: 3rd option: Convert the entire Lambda function to Python. And honestly if the source code in the question is the entire Lambda function, that would be trivial to convert.

Comment: No, this is just the sample code I used to check if my python script will run with nodes, I need the lambda function to be in nodejs.

Comment: Another option is to keep both as separate functions with different runtimes - Node and Python. Invoke one function from another using lambda api or step functions

Comment: @manpreet That's also a good idea. Although I think questions like this come from developers with limited technical expertise and they got a Python script (not Lambda) that someone else wrote which they just want to use without porting it etc. So I am not sure that they would be able to port the Python script to a Python Lambda. But in general, this is another option how to solve this.